# WCF Interoperability Test

Tags: java, php, wcf, web-services, integration-testing

Could anyone please suggest how to test whether WCF with wsHttpBinding you built is interoperable to PHP, Java and other tools?

Is there any tool that exist to test above

Thank you

Comment: The tools to test this would be PHP, Java, and other tools.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, so I need to know PHP, JAVA in order to test wcf. No tool exist that mimics how PHP and JAVA would interpret WCF Serivices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such tool exists for PHP because PHP doesn't have native support for WS-* standards. You always need some specific third party library / framework to make it work. These libraries are usually based on C++ or Java and exposing functionality to PHP. Different libraries can support different feature set. I have previously integrated with [WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/) for PHP and features demanded by customer required complete custom binding for WCF.

The same is theoretically true with Java. In contrast to .NET and its WCF, Java application servers provide different implementations of WS-* standards. WCF team recently [published first preview](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings) of interoperable bindings which should provide only features available by targeted Java client.

Anyway if you want to test that it works you must indeed write a client on the targeted platform. [Here you have very nice article](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2011/06/test-drive-shiny-new-wcf-interop.html) about exposing the service with interoperable binding and consuming the service in Java.

The general tool for testing services is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) but it test just functionality. You still have to understand if your target platform supports additional features required by the service or not.